# How to Enable and Disable Table View cell one by one in Swift 3

Tags: swift

I am new to iOS and I am facing a problem regarding enabling and disabling UITableView cells buttons. I want to enable the first cell button and disable the other cells buttons. When I click on the first cell button, the second cell button gets enabled.

Comment: Are you saying that when a particular cell button is clicked, you need to enable the next cell button ?

Comment: yes,  particular cell button.

Comment: Keep the  track of indexPath that is currently enabled and for all other indexpath path make the btn disabled and on clicking that button change the indexPath value to indexPath+1.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's very helpful for you. It's work for me.

Here we declare global variable for clickable index.

```
  var clickableIndexPath = 0
```

Here we call `tableView` required methods.

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 50
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    cell.checkButton.isEnabled = indexPath.row == clickableIndexPath
    cell.checkButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(buttonTapped(_ :)), for: .touchUpInside)
    return cell
  }
}
```

Here `tableView` cell button action click event.

```
  @objc func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let buttonPostion = sender.convert(sender.bounds.origin, to: tableView)
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPostion) {
      clickableIndexPath =  indexPath.row + 1
      tableView.reloadData()
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        In tableView, there is one delegate called 
    var IndexToSelect = [0]
         func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

        cell.btn.tag = indexPath.row

        cell.checkButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(btnTapped(_ :)), for: .touchUpInside)

        if IndexToSelect.contains(indexPath.row){
        cell.btn.isHidden = true
        or
        cell.btn.isUserInteraction = false
        }else{
        cell.btn.isHidden = false
        or
        cell.btn.isuserinteraction = true
        }
            return cell
        }

        //Do it here what you want
        @objc func btnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
            if sender.tag == 0{
            IndexToSelect = []
            IndexToSelect.append(sender.tag + 1)
            tableView.reloadData()
            }else{
            return
            }
         }
```